# ''Vem aí o maior evento que você já viu''

Tags: pontuação, vírgula

Esta frase estava num shopping por onde eu passeava. Conversando com um amigo, ficamos numa discussão de qual seria a pontuação adequada:

- Vem aí o maior evento que você já viu
- Vem aí, o maior evento que você já viu
- Vem, aí, o maior evento que você já viu

Qual a versão correta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Vem aí o maior evento que você já viu

O Aulete classifica este *aí* [desta forma](http://www.aulete.com.br/a%C3%AD):

> **9.** Indica aproximação ou a iminência de algo: *"Vem aí a neve. Trago os pés como calhaus e olhe que pus dois pares de coturnos de lã"* (Aquilino Ribeiro, Caminhos errados)

Repare-se no exemplo. Aponta imediatamente para que esta primeira frase está correta. No mesmo sentido, a opinião de Teresa Álvares no Ciberdúvidas é [a seguinte](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/expressoes-adverbiais-e-o-uso-da-virgula/3000):

> Relativamente à virgulação dos advérbios, Sá Nogueira é taxativo: «Os advérbios [...] quer [...] [se anteponham, quer se posponham ao verbo], **nunca se separam por vírgulas**, a não ser quando haja alguma intercalação».

De seguida distancia-se um pouco desta opinião, mas em todo o caso há uma preferência pela omissão das vírgulas, exceto quando se trate de «expressões de teor intercalado ou explicativo».

Cunha e Cintra têm uma opinião semelhante (pág. 642 da 1.ª ed. da *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo*, 1984, referências omitidas):

> Quando os adjuntos adverbiais são de pequeno corpo (um advérbio, por exemplo), costuma-se dispensar a vírgula. A vírgula é, porém, de regra quando se pretende realçá-los. Comparem-se estes passos:
>
> - Depois levaram Ricardo para a casa da mãe Avelina.
> - Depois, o engraçado são as passagens de nível, os aparelhos de sinalização, os vagões-cisternas…
> - Depois, tudo caiu em silêncio.

Curioso que os exemplos sejam com *depois*, na pesquisa que fiz no CETEMPúblico por `[lema="vir"] "," [pos="ADV"]`, *depois* aparece frequentemente. Outros exemplos:

> O jovem lateral veio, ainda por cima, de um clube da III Divisão, o Padernense.
>   O que o tempo veio, infelizmente, confirmar.
>   De Londres veio, naturalmente, uma reacção mais fleumática.

A meu ver, há uma diferença substancial entre estes exemplos e a tua terceira frase — «vem aí» forma um grupo prosódico; não há qualquer hipótese de fazer uma pausa entre «vem» e «aí». Se *aí* tivesse um sentido locativo, ainda consigo admiti-lo (talvez com ligeira mudança no significado):

> Em breve hão de vir, daí, muitos problemas.

Resta só o segundo exemplo:

> Vem aí, o maior evento que você já viu.

Caímos no caso típico em que **não** se deve usar a vírgula: para separar o sujeito do verbo. Esta regra não é tão categórica como por vezes se diz, e perderá alguma força pelo facto de o sujeito estar deslocado para depois do verbo. Helder Guégués dá [estes exemplos](http://letratura.blogspot.nl/2006/05/vrgula-com-sujeito-posposto.html):

> - Tem piada, isso que me dizes: eu também reparei nesses tiques de ajeitar o casaco de Manuel Maria Carrilho.
> - Grande treinador, o Mourinho!

Na leitura que faço da frase, não há (nem de perto!) um destaque comparável para *vem aí*. Assim sendo, aplica-se [a regra geral](http://educacao.uol.com.br/dicas-portugues/ult2781u118.jhtm), apesar da posposição do sujeito (como em *existem já muitas cópias*).

Comment: Tou de acordo, mas tenho só uma observação lateral. Eu interpreto a observação do Cunha e Cintra como incluída na alínea d, acerca do *adjunto adverbial antecipado*, em que se enquadram de facto todos os exemplos deles. A impressão com que eu fiquei foi que eles nem sequer consideram o uso de vírgulas para adjuntos adverbiais noutras posições.

Comment: @Jacinto Hmm, tenho de ver isso em contexto no livro quando estiver em minha casa.